# Synchronization of handshake channel with different clock domains

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, timing, protocol, metastability

My course on design of digital systems uses the book "[*Introduction to Asynchronous Circuit Design*](https://backend.orbit.dtu.dk/ws/portalfiles/portal/215895041/JSPA_async_book_2020_PDF.pdf)" by Jens Sparsø.

On page 156 he talks about synchronizing a handshake protocol between a transmitter and a receiver that have different clock domains. This is done by placing DFF's synchronized locally in the request and acknowledgement signal paths as seen below. He also emphasizes that it is a big mistake to synchronize the data signals but it not obvious to me why. Here is an excerpt: -

[image]

It is explained very briefly and I don't quite understand why it is such a big mistake to synchronize the data signals. Can someone clarify this, or maybe use an alternative explanation to the one used by author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronizing the data just adds latency to it. You don't want or need that: the data are guaranteed to be held stable until the handshake completes its round trip, ensuring its setup and hold time at the receiver, in the receiver's clock domain.

One caution about synchronizing handshakes across clock boundaries: if the receiver issues any kind of backpressure (e.g., its FIFO going full) the sender may need a *skid buffer* to cover the added handshake latency inserted by the two clock domain crossings. Most often, this can be mitigated by using an 'almost full' signal at the receiver, with enough extra entries in its FIFO to cover the latency. The slower the receiver is, the more entries you need.

Answer (score 3):

Metastability can occur when the setup time to a register is not met. By register, consider a D-type Flip-Flop (DFF).

On such a bus, handshaking signals are intended to indicate when the associated signals contain stable data that won't change during handshaking. Because the data won't be changing, there are no concerns about metastability. That's the point of the handshaking protocol: to be the only part that changes what the data to transfer is steady.

So here, the data cannot change when the handshaking signals do. This can be:

- Producer asserts REQ a delay after DATA changed, or
- Consumer waits after detecting REQ before taking DATA.

An example protocol would be:

```
PRODUCER: Latch new data out on DATA.
          Delay.
          Assert REQ.

CONSUMER: Detect REQ asserted after domain crossing.
          Latch stable data from DATA.
          Assert ACK.

PRODUCER: Detect ACK asserted after domain crossing.
          Negate REQ.
          Wait for ACK negated after domain crossing.
```

Simpler and faster methods exist but this shows the principles.

Answer (score 2):

If the data signals were synchronised with the same number of DFF's as used for the *Req* signal, then the set-up time of the synchronised data signals w.r.t the synchronised *Req* might not be met at the consumer.

Whereas just synchronising the *Req* signal means that by the time the *Req* signal is sampled as asserted by the consumer the data should be stable.

I realise this answer might be too brief as just words and:

1. Might need a timing diagram added.
2. The number of DFF's required could depend upon upon the relative frequencies of *Clk_P* and *Clk_C*.

   Taking the example of [Clock Domain Crossing MTBF Options](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/pg059-axi-interconnect/Clock-Domain-Crossing-MTBF-Options) from the Xilinx *AXI Interconnect v2.1 LogiCORE IP Product Guide* the number of
   *Synchronization Stages* can be adjusted. However, that document doesn't seem to give any guidance on how the number of *Synchronization Stages* should be determined:

   > Description: Specifies the number of synchronization stages used in any asynchronous clock domain conversion couplers instantiated within the AXI Interconnect core.
   >
   > Format/Range: Integer (**2-8**)
   >
   > Default: 2

Answer (score 2):

I'll draw a timing diagram, but this is what could happen.

Look at your first double FF synchronization circuit shown, the one going from left to right.  Assume that the Req signal changes fro 0 to 1 close enough to Clk_C so that the first FF goes metastable.  On the next clock edge the second FF could resolve that signal as a 0, a 1, or in a very rare case, another metastable case.  We'll ignore that one for now.

If the second FF resolves it as a 0, then on the next clock the Req change to a 1 would come through to the consumer.  If the second FF resolves it as a 1, the the Req signal =1 comes through on first clock edge.

So the difference in the two case is a 2 vs 1 clock delay before the Req=1 is presented to the consumer.

So if you have multiple bits involved (as in a n-bit bus), you should be able to see how the bits in the "word" could get scrambled.

I experienced something like this on a byte basis.  We had a 16 bits of parallel data coming in to 2 separate 8-bit FIFOs.  The FIFO's were held in reset which was then released asynchronously wrt the incoming data.  Sometimes, coming out of reset the 2 FIFO's would both capture the 2 bytes associated with the 16-bit word correctly, but sometimes one would miss it's first byte.  From that point onward the 2 FIFO's were misaligned, with one having data from sample n while the other had data from n+1 in the same location.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous data can take 2 or 3 clock cycles to pass through a double flip flop synchronizer. It’s pretty much random whether it takes 2 or 3. A synchronizer can “miss” a value change, so the value has to be applied for at least 2 clock cycles of the consumer.

If you use synchronizers for the data (plus a valid bit so you know when to sample the data) it can happen that the valid bit only needs 2 clock cycles to travel through the synchronizers while some of the data bits need 3 clock cycles.

The solution is to don’t use synchronizers for the data bits. Just make sure the data is stable when the valid bit has passed through its synchronizer so the setup and hold time requirements of your consumer flip flops are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that data is grabbed reliably, the number of flip flops in each flop domain must be at least as great for request as for data, and the number in at least one of the domains must be greater for request than for data.  In many situations, the easiest way to satisfy this requirement may be to eliminate synchronization for data.  Such an approach may not always be without risk or complications, however.

Suppose, for example, that one of the data inputs is used, along with the request bit and some "clock state" bits, as an input to a look-up table to select the next state.  Logic may be designed so that if it's in state 1, it will advance to state 2 if the data is low, and it will advance to state 2 if the data is high.  This approach will work if the data is fed through a synchronizer, but may fail if it is used with an unsynchronized data signal.